# Convert object to type given by string or typeof(number[])

Tags: javascript

i like to convert a type given by a string, because i want to convert a string of numbers to an array of numbers.

```
var myStringType = "number[]";
var myString = "0, 0, 0";

var myStringArray = myString.Split(","); <- these array need to be a array;
var myNumbersArray = ConvertToAnyByString(myStringArray, myStringType);
```

I can convert by knowing the type, if the method above is not possible. Is there something like compare against typeof(number[])

***Update:
I think here is a misunderstanding. I don't know which type will passed to my function. I need type check that or convert it by a string information which type it is. And there is no way to do that natively in javascript, because there is no type of arrayOfStrings there is just a array. But i can make a helper functions to do this by hand.***

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask but if you do `'0,0,0'.split(',')` that'll actually give you an array `["0", "0", "0"]`.

Comment: @Rishabh I've a string and it need to be a number array not a string array.

Comment: You need to clarify 2 things please:

 * Do you expect to always have numbers in the array, or do you need to filter out errors (empty slots, text)?
 * Ints or Floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment you can do (without `.map` or shim for `.map`):

```
var str = '0,1,8';
var arr = str.split(','), L=arr.length;
          while(L--){arr[L]=Number(arr[L]);}
//now arr contains numbers.
```

here `Number(arr[L]);` is the 'payload' but you also could use (depending on what you need):
`parseInt(arr[L]);` or `parseFloat(arr[L]);` or `arr[L]*1;` or even simply `+arr[L];`
as a payload. It's just what floats your boat.

test with: `alert(typeof arr[1]); // number`

---

But to actually answer the question that you originally asked *(convert values in a array to a different type specified by a string)*, I offer this simple example to give an *idea* how one *could* do this:

```
var convertArrToAnyByString = function(arr,converTo,rad){
   var L = arr.length;
   rad = rad||10;  // optional, defaults to 10 as radix
   switch(converTo){
     case 'number':
        while(L--){arr[L] = Number(arr[L]);}
        break;
     case 'string':
        while(L--){arr[L] = arr[L].toString(rad);}
        break;
     default:
        arr=false;
   }
   return arr;
};

var str = '0,1,8';
var arr = str.split(','); 

// testing:
alert(typeof arr[1]);  //arr[1] should be string by default
arr=convertArrToAnyByString(arr,'number');
alert(typeof arr[1]);  // number
arr=convertArrToAnyByString(arr,'string');
alert(typeof arr[1]);  // string again
alert(arr[2]);         // still 8
```

You can easily expand on this example by adding types and even error-checking.

Good Luck!

Comment: @Jack: *thank you for the kind nudge*. I've converted from lower case l to uppercase L just last month and missed that last l. Updated answer. Yes, tested.

Answer (score 2):

OK. try this -

```
var str = '0,0,0';
var arr = str.split(','); // ['0', '0', '0']
var int_arr = arr.map(function(el) {return parseInt(el, 10);}); // [0, 0, 0]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sure the OP expects only Ints, & not Floats?

Comment: note that prototype map on array is new ES5 and thus not browser-compatible at all. Also, the shim needed is quite big.

Comment: @GitaarLAB we can't all dwell in the past :) besides, the shim can be made quite small.